# Integrating Nunjucks with IntelliJ IDEA / Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, webstorm, nunjucks

How can I add syntax highlighting to [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) template files in IntelliJ IDEA / Webstorm?

There is no obvious plugin available.  Perhaps there is something for a similar templating engine that would work?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just found a [solution](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/472#issuecomment-123219907).  Configure a custom extension with **Twig** files.  It's a template engine with similar syntax (but for PHP).

1. add **Twig Support** plugin if necessary
2. Go to Settings -> Editor -> File Types and add find **Twig**
3. Add the custom pattern `*.njk`.

Now all `*.njk` files are parsed as Twig so in the end you have support for Nunjucks.

Comment: Yeah just to be clear, though it's not required, the docs for Nunjuks state that we should be using `.njk` as the recommended extension now (see 'file extensions' section here: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html)

Answer (score 8):

Webstorm don't has build-in TWIG support.
You need to manually download it from here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7303 then choose `Preferences > Plugins > Install plugin from disk...` and chose the file you just downloaded.
Then follow [FireCoding's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558700/2594907).
Worked perfectly for me in Webstorm 11.0.3

Comment: Looks like newer versions of Webstorm (I'm on `2018.1.3` support TWIG natively). So this step isn't necessary anymore.